# Help me finish this misery from I don't know who?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I have four puzzler friends Levy, Aron, Roxy and Cass. Last night when I was just about to sleep, a stone came straight through my window. It had a puzzle on it.

It read:

**SOLVE IT SHORTEST!**

```
00110001b 01100101b 00110100b 01001110b 01100011b 00110110b 00110010b 01100100b 00110100b 01001110b 01100110b 00110110b 00110011b 01100101b 00110101b 01001110b 01100100b 00110101b 00110100b 01001110b 01100110b 00110011b 01100010b 00110110b 00110101b 01000010b 01100011b 00110100b 01100101b 00110110b 00110110b 01001111b 00101101b 01001111b 01000010b 01100010b 00110111b 00110111b 01000010b 01100010b 00110011b 01001110b 01100001b 00110101b 00111000b 01000010b 01111000b 01100100b 00110101b 01100101b 01111000b 01100100b 00110101b 00111001b 01100010b 00110100b 01001110b 01100011b 00110100b 00110001b 00110000b 01001110b 01100010b 01100100b 00110010b 01000010b 01100001b 00110110b 00110001b 00110001b 01001110b 01111000b 01100011b 00110100b 01100100b 01111000b 01100011b 00110100b 00110001b 00110010b 01100011b 00110011b 01100100b 00110110b 00110001b 00110011b 01010010b 01100101b 00110001b 01000010b 01100010b 00110111b 00110001b 00110100b 01100101b 01111000b 01100100b 00110110b 00101011b 01001011b 01100100b 00110111b 00110001b 00110101b 01100100b 01111000b 01100011b 00110111b 01010001b 01111000b 01100011b 00110111b 00110001b 00110110b 01001110b 01100101b 00110101b 00101011b 01001011b 01100100b 00111000b 00110001b 00110111b 01000010b 01100110b 00110100b 01001011b 01100011b 00111000b 00110001b 00111000b 01010001b 01100111b 00110100b 00101011b 01001011b 01100010b 00111000b 00110001b 00111001b 01001110b 01111000b 01100110b 00110111b 01000010b 01100100b 00110110b 00110010b 00110000b 01000010b 01111000b 01100100b 00110110b 01101000b 00110101b 00110010b 00110001b 01000010b 01111000b 01100011b 00110111b 00101011b 01001011b 01111000b 01100011b 00110111b 00110010b 00110010b 01010001b 01100110b 00110100b 00101011b 01001011b 01100011b 00110110b 00110010b 00110011b 01010001b 01100100b 00110110b 00101011b 01001011b 01100010b 00110101b 00110010b 00110100b 01100001b 00110100b 00101011b 01001011b 01100001b 00110110
```

I solved it, and it also told me who threw the stone.

Can you?

Comment: I don't get why your friends are hating on short people

Comment: For the last tuple/piece, **b** is missing. Is it intentional or should it be there?

Comment: @Adib you got it in the wrong sense.

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay it is quite intentional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a

> Chess game

Exactly, it's a

> Chess game written in [Algebraic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_%28chess%29) itself coded in ascii code written in binary format.

If we decode the binary code and reshape it, we got :

> 1 e4 Nc6        
>  2 d4 Nf6        
>  3 e5 Nd5        
>  4 Nf3 b6        
>  5 Bc4 e6        
>  6 O-O Bb7       
>  7 Bb3 Na5       
>  8 Bxd5 exd5     
>  9 b4 Nc4        
>  10 Nbd2 Ba6     
>  11 Nxc4 dxc4    
>  12 c3 d6        
>  13 Re1 Bb7      
>  14 exd6+ Kd7    
>  15 dxc7 Qxc7     
>  16 Ne5+ Kd8     
>  17 Bf4 Kc8      
>  18 Qg4+ Kb8     
>  19 Nxf7 Bd6     
>  20 Bxd6 h5      
>  21 Bxc7+ Kxc7   
>  22 Qf4+ Kc6     
>  23 Qd6+ Kb5     
>  24 a4+ Ka6

So the solution is

> 25 b5+ Ka5 
>  26 Qb4+ #

Comment: So... who threw the stone?

Comment: What is the significance of the Bs trailing the binary, and why does the last binary not have one?

Can you include the chess moves after they have been converted from ascii?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [purplepsycho](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/40847/purplepsycho)'s answer the person who threw the stone was:

> Aron

Because:

> 1. e4 Nc6 is [Nimzowitsch Defence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimzowitsch_Defence) named after [**Aron** Nimzowitsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aron_Nimzowitsch)

Comment: I found it's name too, but why would he trew the stone? Or someone playing versus him on a famous game?

Comment: We know that the solution told him who threw the stone and we know that his friends are puzzlers so I think assuming that it's because of the same name is reasonable. @purplepsycho

Comment: +1. Although purple solved the main part so I had to accept his answer.

Comment: Okay. How are two people who share a name logically connected?